# Information Exposure Through Sent Data (CWE ID 201)

Tags: java, security, veracode

I am getting Information Exposure Through Sent Data (CWE ID 201) from veracode on this line.

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+reportName+".pdf\"");
```

How do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

ESAPI HTTP utilities did it for me:

```
ESAPI.httpUtilities().setHeader(response,param,value);
```

- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API